# What is "epistemic probability"?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, classical-mechanics, quantum-mechanics

In classical mechanics, states can be formalized as probability measures on phase space, i.e. $\pi_t:\operatorname{Bor}(\mathscr F)\to[0,1]$ (parametrized by time) satisfying the usual probability axioms for all $t$. The number $\pi_t(E)$ can be interpreted as the probability that the *actual representative point* of the system, $(\boldsymbol q(t),\boldsymbol p(t))$ is contained in the set $E$.

Some of these measures are absolutely continuous at all times w.r.t. the Liouville volume measure (stemming from the standard symplectic form $\omega = dp_i \wedge dq^i$), so they admit a Radon-Nikodym derivative $\rho_t$ with the meaning of probability density; other states do not, and among these are the Dirac states (one could call them *pure states*), i.e.
$$\delta_x(E) = \begin{cases}
1 & x \in E,\\
0 & x \notin E,
\end{cases} $$
which take the meaning of "perfectly localized" states (states with zero variance). It is not hard to convince oneself that the set of states is a *convex set* (it contains every convex combination, i.e. *incoherent superposition*, of its elements).

What I just described is the formalization of an **epistemic uncertainty** about the "true state of a system": this is because classically speaking the system *will* trace out a trajectory in phase space under the action of Hamilton's equations, so it *really does* admit a representative point $(\boldsymbol q(t),\boldsymbol p(t))$ at all times, I just *don't always know it exactly* (as is mostly the case in the statistical mechanics of systems with a large number of degrees of freedom).

In quantum mechanics, on the other hand, states are formalized as measures on the lattice of projectors on a particular Hilbert space $\mathscr H$, or equivalently (by Gleason's theorem), as trace-class operators $\rho$ (suppressing the time dependency for simplicity) with unit trace. These also form a convex set under incoherent superposition, and always admit a decomposition (by the spectral theorem)
$$\rho = \sum_n p_n (\psi_n,–)\psi_n, \tag{$\star$} $$
for an orthonormal eigenbasis $\psi_n$ of $\mathscr H$, with $p_n\geq 0$ and $\sum_n p_n =1$. When $\rho = (\psi,–)\psi$ for some normalized $\psi \in \mathscr H$, then it describes a *pure quantum state* (in one-to-one correspondence with a ray in $\mathscr H$); however, $(\star)$ does **not** describe an epistemic uncertainty, because in general, the eigenbasis is not unique (think $\rho=1/{(\dim\mathscr H)}\cdot\mathbb{I}_\mathscr H$ when $\dim\mathscr H<\infty$).

> Is there a mathematical definition, or a characterization, of a (convex?) family of probability measures, that establishes when its elements can be interpreted to represent epistemic uncertainty vs. when they don't?
>
> To me, it looks like it should have something to do with the fact that classical systems admit perfectly localized states (Dirac measures), which could be seen as "deterministic" (they attain values in $\{0,1\}$), whereas quantum systems *do not* (by the Kochen–Specker theorem). However, I wouldn't know if this property already had a name in measure theory.

Comment: I don't know the quantum mechanics formalism, but can't any valid [probability measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_measure) be interpreted as representing epistemic uncertainty? The measure of a set $S$ of outcomes is the probability that the "true outcome" lies in $S$.

Comment: I don't understand what you ask. I haven't read anything that supports the probabilities, in quantum mechanics, to be of epistemic nature, and quite the contrary, actually.

Comment: What I mean is: if the probabilities in quantum mechanics are known to be non-epistemic, this must not be due to a property of the probability measure itself but due to some other information about the process that generates those probabilities. If we're given *only* a measure space with a probability measure on it, there's nothing in that data that could prevent us from interpreting the probabilities as epistemic. The question seems to ask for such a criterion.

Comment: @Karl I actually hint at a possible criterion at the end. I just don’t know how measure theoreticians who have nothing to do with physics would refer to it.

Comment: I'm arguing that there's no such criterion for probability measures in general. The definition of a probability measure doesn't involve "states" as you describe them, it just assigns probabilities to sets of outcomes. Anyway, hopefully someone familiar with quantum mechanics can provide a more useful answer.